# Agregar botones sobre imagen que cambia tamaño dinamicamente

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html5, canvas

Necesito ayuda para colocar botones en una imagen ,la imagen tiene zoom asi que cambia los pixeles constantemente dependiendo del evento de alejar o acercar ,trate con la etiqueta `<map>` pero esta solo se le puede dar color con la etiqueta `<area>` lo que quisiera es que el boton no se mueva aunque se acerque o aleje la imagen algo parecido a esto.

example:

```html
<img src="https://www.w3schools.com/tags/planets.gif" alt="Planets"usemap="#planetmap">

<map name="planetmap">
  <input type="button" coords="0,0,82,126" >
  <input type="button" coords="90,58,3">
  <input type="button" coords="124,58,8">
</map>
```

Comment: Por curiosidad: ¿por qué redactaste la pregunta en inglés? ¿Llegaste desde Stack Overflow o accediste directamente a Stack Overflow en español? Nos encontramos con este caso diariamente y sería útil saber el motivo, para poder mostrar la información de manera más clara, explicitando que este es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas en castellano.

Comment: Veo que tu codigo lo sacaste más o menos de [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_areamap).. pero ahi usan `<area>` en vez de `<input>`.

Comment: exactamente pero en el map no se puede agregar input ,lo que nesecito es que el boton no se mueva de la coordenada aunque se aleje la imagen o se acerque.

Comment: Ahhh y si las coordenadas son actualizadas  en funcion del zoom aplicado?  Igual es un lio de  matematicas ...

Comment: Bueno lo pense pero es que quiero agregarle el boton a la imagen porque es un plano de un edificio y lo que hara es cambiar el estado del boton si esta ocupado o no como si fuera el sistema de reserva de los cines solo que la imagen debe ser responsive y tener el zoom para poder alejar y acercar en los dispositivos.

Comment: ok pero el código de w3school no es zoom, simplemente reemplaza la imagen por otra, quizás debas buscar otra forma de hacer zoom, o explicar bien que es lo que quieres porque en lo personal no te entiendo mucho cual es el fin, estas hablando de zoom cuando lo que intentas emular es un reemplazo de imágenes que simulan zoom

Comment: Bueno es que la imagen tampoco es estatica esta cambiara dependiendo de la planta que se escoja ,esto lo estoy haciendo en html inicialmente pero despues se cargara con datos de una base lo que hara que el plano de la imagen cambie igual que los botones digan numero de puesto y te haga una reserva.

Comment: Bueno para hacerlo simple es un sistema de reserva,la imagen es dinamica tiene zoom porque seria para dispositivos moviles por eso nesecita agrandar la imagen o alejarla

Comment: solo nesecito agregar los botones en una coodenada de la imagen especificamente y que el boton no se mueva de esa coordenada aun con el zoom , esta es la plantilla de zoom que utilizo.

Comment: https://www.cssscript.com/demo/touch-enabled-image-zoom-plugin-javascript/